# "projective maassbestimmung" in Automorphic Functions by Fricke + Klein

Tags: projective-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, translation-request

I was reading a copy of Fricke and Klein's Theory of Automorphic Forms, and I came across the phrase ***projective maassbestimmung*** in the first chapter.

Google translate returns: [maßbestimmung](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/ma%C3%9Fbestimmung) as *determination of measure*.

Maybe this could just be projecive space, but I found [*projective Raum*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projektiver_Raum) for that.

---

Similarly I found  ***hyperbolicshe massbestimmung*** which could be *hyperbolic space* or *geometry*?  In that case, I found [*hyperbolische Geometrie*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolische_Geometrie).

Comment: Just from the german I think he means measure in projective space, but maybe just read the book to see if the definitions there confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as if "Maßbestimmung" is an old word for "Metrik" (metric).

Addendum: A quick Google search shows that at least in [this book](http://books.google.de/books?id=EAPX3JfQAgIC&lpg=PA380&ots=-5aWZgIopR&dq=massbestimmung%20metric&pg=PA380#v=onepage&q=massbestimmung%20metric&f=false) (on page 380) they used that translation.